# Number input min attribute not working with floats

Tags: javascript, html

With the below HTML, when I type the value `3` in the input and click on `submit`, Chrome (at least) shows the following **error** in a popup:

```
Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 2.0001 and 3.0001.
```

This doesn't make sense. I've set the **minimum** value to be **0.0001** and I'm entering **3** which is **greater than 0.0001**.

```js
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <input placeholder="0.000" 
         id="something" 
         type="number" 
         name="something" 
         min="0.0001" 
         required>
       
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value for the [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step) attribute is `1`, and since you've a `min` applied on your input, there's *no* integral `n` such that `min + n * step` (`0.0001 + n * 1`) equals `3`.

You can change the step to `0.0001` or `any`.

```js
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.elements[0].value);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="onSubmit">
  <input
    placeholder="0.000"
    id="something"
    type="number"
    name="something"
    min="0.0001"
    step="any"
    required
  >
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't `step` is involved even when it's not explicitly defined.. Thanks :)